# Как перетасовать строки?

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день.

Я из БД вывожу строки вариантов для тестовой программы. Как мне перетасовать строки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вывести 20 случайных строк из таблицы:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

Или потом в php перемешать массив ф-ей [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз только тоже нашел))